# Javascript using $ notation and keyword "this" usage

Tags: javascript, this

I am working on someone else's javascript code and I run in some things I have not seen used before. I would really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on it for me. 
I have used javascript in the past but I am not by any means an expert.

1) Some controls are accessed from within javascript using dollar sign ($) notation, just like JQuery. I am slightly puzzled as the scripting language is clearly specified as javascript, not JQuery and there are no JQuery libraries in the project. I wa wondering if that was a common practice?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function select1_onchange()
{
    $('Button1').style.display = (this.value == "No" ? 'block' : 'none');
    $('OptionsBox').style.display = (this.value == "Yes" ? 'block' : 'none');
}
</script>
```

2) Second thing is that in code above, keyword `this` seems to refer to the object calling the script, meanwhile in the current context javascript interprets `this` and the `window` object. Which makes this code invalid.
Should I replace `this.value` with `$('Button1').value` or `document.getElementById('Button1')` (or document.getElementsByName('Button1')[0] in this particular case since the developer used `name` attribute instead of `id`)? Which one would be more efficient? Or another option - should I pass keyword `this` to the function and then replace `this` with the input variable?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function select1_onchange(mySelect)
{
    $('Button1').style.display = (mySelect.value == "No" ? 'block' : 'none');
    $('OptionsBox').style.display = (mySelect.value == "Yes" ? 'block' : 'none');
}
</script>
```

and call it as:

```
<select name="select1" onchange="select1_onchange(this)">
<option selected value="">Select</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

What would be some pros and cons of choosing either method?

Comment: You'll have to find out what `$` is. jQuery is JavaScript, and `type="text/javascript"` is unnecesary.

Comment: jQuery **is** Javascript. Anytime you see jQuery, that is Javascript code. They're just using the jQuery library. That's like saying "there's bacon on there so it can't be a burger." It's still a burger, you just added bacon to it.

Comment: from the looks of it he defined $ as a shortcut for getElementById, are `Button1` and `OptionsBox` ids?

Comment: They must have included JQuery somewhere if they are using $(id) notation to getElementByID.

Comment: @Anup Not true. Look at adeneo's answer. That's probably what they did.

Comment: ya that might be true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone probably created their own little function, something like

```
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

$('Button1').style.display = 'none';
```

jQuery is written somewhat the same way, in plain javascript, as it's just a library of convenient  *"helper functions"*.
To check if jQuery is present, one can do `typeof jQuery`, which should return `"function"`

When you attach an inline event handler, you can pass arguments

```html
<select name="select1" onchange="select1_onchange('hello kitty')">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

<script>
    function select1_onchange(something) {
        alert(something); // "hello kitty"
    }
</script>
```

Passing `this` instead of a string, gives a reference to an element, in most cases it would be the `window`, so it's not really something that is commonly done

```html
<select name="select1" onchange="select1_onchange(this)">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

<script>
    function select1_onchange(something) {
        alert(this); // [object Window]
    }
</script>
```

These days, [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) should be used instead, which automatically sets the `this` value inside the callback to the bound element.

```html
<select name="select1" id="select1">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

<script>
  
  document.getElementById('select1').addEventListener('change', function() {
    alert(this.id); // "select1"
  }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Agreed. In JavaScript `$` is a valid variable name. The jQuery library uses a variable named `$` as an alias to the jQuery object, but the presence of a variable named `$` doesn't mean that the jQuery library is present. You can usually check for the presence of the jQuery library by looking for a variable named `jQuery`.

Comment: This is not a totally complete answer, given that $ is NOT a function that they wrote. It definitely is something that browser devtools are doing now as an alias for document.querySelector. http://thewebivore.com/exactly-wth-is-up-with-in-devtools/

Moreover the "this" refers to the element that called the function because it is an inline handler

Comment: @NodeNodeNode - if ran in the console, that's true, most browser will have their own `$` function. However this is code written in a script tag, in a .html file, and the `$` from the dev-tools isn't available in that scope. As for what `this` refers to, there's a snippet attached, you're free to try it out.

Comment: adeneo, your solution to the first one was right on!   As far as the second part goes, what would be preferential, replacing keyword this with document.getElementsbyName('Button1')[0] or using another method? if so, which one should I use and why?

Comment: There are many ways to select an element, you choose whatever fits. If `.getElementsbyName('Button1')[0]` works for you, that's great, and there's nothing wrong with it, it selects the first element with that name.

Comment: passing "this" from the function that is being called inline also works. I was wondering which would be most stable and efficient in my case

Comment: Generally, one should stay away from inline event handlers, seperation of concerns etc.

Answer (score 2):

1) jQuery is only a javascript library: it's still javascript. jQuery's api is exposed through the "jQuery" object that has the "$" variable as an alias.

2) The keyword "this" in javascript refers to the parent scope, so the scope of the function in the case of the example provided above.